# how to change the position of nav items buttons on react.js using mui library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvifU.png)

//this is my code i was trying to change the position of the nav bar buttons to make space between them
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

//this is my code i was trying to change the position of the nav bar buttons to make space between them

```
 import * as React from 'react';
    import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
    import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
    import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
    import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
    import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
    import List from '@mui/material/List';
    import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
    import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
    import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
    import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
    import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
    import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
    import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
    import EngineeringIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Engineering';
    interface Props {
      /**
       * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
       * You won't need it on your project.
       */
      window?: () => Window;
    }
    
    const drawerWidth = 240;
    const navItems = ['Home', 'About Me', 'Contact'];
    
    export default function DrawerAppBar(props: Props) {
      const { window } = props;
      const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
    
      const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
        setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
      };
    
      const drawer = (
        <Box onClick={handleDrawerToggle} sx={{ textAlign: 'center'}} >
          <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ my: 2 }} >
            MUI
          </Typography>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {navItems.map((item) => (
              <ListItem key={item} disablePadding>
                <ListItemButton sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  <ListItemText primary={item} />
                </ListItemButton>
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Box>
      );
    
      const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;
    
      return (
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
          <AppBar component="nav" style={{ background:'#5689c0' }} >
            <Toolbar variant="dense">
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="open drawer"
                edge="start"
                onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
                sx={{ mr: 2, display: { sm: 'none' } }}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography
                variant="h6"
                component="div"
                sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}
              >
               <EngineeringIcon fontSize='large' />
              </Typography>
              <Box sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}>
                {navItems.map((item) => (
                  <Button key={item} sx={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                    {item}
                  </Button>
                ))}
              </Box>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <Box component="nav">
            <Drawer
              container={container}
              variant="temporary"
              open={mobileOpen}
              onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
              ModalProps={{
                keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
              }}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'none' },
                '& .MuiDrawer-paper': { boxSizing: 'border-box', width: drawerWidth },
              }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Box>
          <Box component="main" sx={{ p: 0 }}>
            <Toolbar />
          
          </Box>
        </Box>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of elements in `navItems` array

```
const navItems = ['About Me', 'Home', 'Contact'];
```

Now `About Me` will show before `Home`